# Как из функции вывести данные в условие другой функции

Tags: wordpress

Функция **sub_cat_1** выводит массив под категорий главной категории **1**

```
function sub_cat_1(){
 $term_id = 1;
 $taxonomy_name = 'category';
 $term_children = get_term_children( $term_id, $taxonomy_name );
 foreach ( $term_children as $child ) {
  $term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomy_name );
  echo '' . $term->term_id . ',';
 }
}
```

Нужно вывести этот массив под категорий в функцию **custom_posts_per_page** в условие **is_category**

```
function custom_posts_per_page($query){
 if( $query->is_category(sub_cat_1()) && $query->is_main_query() && !is_admin() ){
  //обработка
 }
}
```

Первая функция верно выводит все под категории указанной категории 1 в нужной форме для **is_category()**.
Вторая функция не получает в **is_category()** эти под категории, но выводит их в самый верх сайта перед .
Также делал перед условием так:

```
function custom_posts_per_page($query){
 $ids = sub_cat_1();
 if( $query->is_category($ids) && $query->is_main_query() && !is_admin() ){}
}
```

И тоже выводит в самый верх сайта массив, я так понимаю проблема в первой функции, в **foreach**
Подскажите, как правильно вывести в условие

Answer (score 0):

```
function sub_cat_1(){
     $term_id = 1;
     $taxonomy_name = 'category';
     $term_children = get_term_children( $term_id, $taxonomy_name );
    $cats = array();
     foreach ( $term_children as $child ) {
      $term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomy_name );
      $cats[] = $term->term_id;
     }
    return implode(',', $cats);
}
```